# Visual Studio 2015 Cordova iOS .ipa Location

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I'm trying to release an iOS app built using Visual Studio 2015 Cordova Tools.  I can deploy to the simulator and to my device just fine.  But I can't find where the .ipa file is being created?  My bin/iOS/release folder is empty even after cleaning solution, restarting, and rebuilding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried with the latest versions, but I never found that I could build a release version from VS for iOS.  I always went and opened the project on the Mac with XCode, using the project in the remote-build folder, tweaked the project settings (VS project never seems to allow multiple device orientations, I need to check on the others, choose the correct developer profile, and usually correct the bundle identifier).  Then build and submit to app store from XCode as a normal iOS app.

Perhaps the latest versions are better on this, but I doubt you will find the app bundle in your VS solution folders, it would have to be on the Mac.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the orientation.  I also had to change my provisioning profiles and disable Bitcode (even though I had done that already in Visual Studio).